# Select the whole week with primefaces <p:calendar>

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces, jquery-ui-datepicker

How can I customize p:calendar so instead of selecting a day (chell) in a week I will be able to select the all week (row)?

[like this example](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerSelectWeek.html)

Thanks